# create two arrays based on what meet a condition and the diff

Tags: arrays, ruby

Lets suppose I've the follow array:

```
a = [1,2,3]
```

I want to split it in two arrays from it, one with items for which a condition is true, and other for which the same condition is false:

```
b, c = a.split_in_two_arrays_or_something_like_that {|x| x == 3}
#=> b = [3]
#=> c = [1,2]
```

How can I do that in ruby? I don't want to repeat code with something like:

```
b = a.reject {|x| x == 3}
c = a.reject {|x| x != 3}
```

Nor iterate over the array twice.

Is there some method that return me something different than the modified array? For example, `delete_if` will work if it would return the deleted elements, but the original array would've keeped the same, but it doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Enumerable#partition](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-partition) to separate the elements in your array according to a condition. We define the condition in `partition`'s block:

```
a = [1,2,3]

b, c = a.partition { |x| x == 3 } #=> [[3], [1, 2]]

b #=> [3]
c #=> [1, 2]
```

This method creates an array with two subarrays.

- The first subarray contains the values for which `partition`'s block returns **true**.
- The second subarray contains the values for which `partition`'s block returns **false**.

Finally we apply parallel-assignment to assign variables **b** to the first subarray and **c** to the second.